# Displaying 'Appendix' in the header of the Appendix (even pages)

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I really can't understand why the word "Appendix" doesn't show up in the header of my appendix the way "Bibliography" shows up on the pages of my bibliography.

What did I do wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,header]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{textcomp}                       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                               
\usepackage{booktabs}                                               
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang,
            justification=RaggedRight,              
            singlelinecheck=off,                        
            labelfont=bf,                                   
            font=footnotesize,
            textfont=footnotesize,
            twoside,
            labelsep=colon
            ]{caption}  
                                    
\usepackage[language=autobib,
    backend=biber                               %%%% switch on/off 
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
toc,
page,
title,
titletoc,
header
]{appendix}
%%%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First  Section}

Hello.

\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{example-image-a}
\end{figure} 

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

Hello again!

\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{example-image-b}
\end{figure} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{appendices}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}

\section*{First part of the appendix}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{example-image-c}
\end{figure} 

\newpage

\section*{Second part of the appendix}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image}
\end{figure} 

\newpage

\section*{Third part of the appendix}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image2}
\end{figure} 


\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appendices are just chapters with a different name, so the running heads will alternate, with the "chapter" title on the left page and the section heading on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
    \begin{appendices}
    
    \markboth{Appendix}{Appendix} % added <<<<<
```

[image: c]

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!